Why Isn't the Virtual Keyboard Appearing on Mobile Devices for My Keyboard Tester?
I'm a beginner working on my third or fourth project, and I'm encountering an issue with my keyboard tester application. The project is named KeyMaster, and it works perfectly fine on PC browsers for testing keyboard events. However, I am having trouble getting the virtual keyboard to appear on mobile browsers.
Here’s a brief overview of my setup:

Repository Link: GitHub - CASIOmax/Keyboard-Tester

index.html Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"> 
    <title>KeyMaster</title>
</head>
<body id="Sudo-Body">
    <div class="maindiv">
    <div id="insert"> Press any Keyboard key to see the magic!</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="hiddenInput" style="position: absolute; top: -100px;" />
</body>
    <script src="spirit.js"></script>
</html>


spirit.js Code:
const colorGen = function() {
    const hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

const insert = document.getElementById('insert');
const hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  hiddenInput.focus();
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const rand = colorGen();
    insert.innerHTML = `
    <table style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">key</th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">keyCode</th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">${e.key === " " ? "Space" : e.key}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">${e.keyCode}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid ${rand};">${e.code}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
  insert.style.color = "white";
});



Issue:
The virtual keyboard does not appear on mobile browsers when the user touches the screen. I’ve included an invisible input field to trigger the keyboard, but it seems not to work as expected on mobile devices.
What I’ve Tried:

Ensuring the input field is focused when the screen is touched.
Using contenteditable as an alternative.
Checking for any CSS or JavaScript that might be interfering.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Are you seeing this on both iOS and android systems?

Yes I have tried for both android (Redmi 13C)and IOS (Iphone 11)

Does your event handler for touchstart run at all? Do an alert('touched') inside the callback to check. Maybe window.addEventListener('touchstart') is more effective? Or using the click event? Does it work if your input is not visually hidden?

Yes I tried console.log("Tested!");. And it appears in the console that means the event handler is running.  alert('touched') is also working, as it displays the message box stating touched. Tried using click same results. Making input field visual allows the keyboard to popup. But I think the mobile browsers key board works differently. To catch the keys accurately on mobile device browsers I need to make major changes to the code itself. Normally for now if I press any key on mobile keyboard it displays the key as unidentified.
